# U-Substitution Integral Problem

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve the following homework problem.

$\int_{26}^{27} x \sqrt{x - 26} \ dx$

This is what I have atttempted so far:
$u = x - 26; du = 1$

$\int_{26}^{27} \sqrt{u} \ du$

$ x = 26 \rightarrow u = 0$
$ x = 27 \rightarrow u = 1$

$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{u} \ du$

$ = ( \frac{2}{3} \times \sqrt{u^3})$ Evaluated at x = 1 - 0

This seems to give me a completely incorrect answer though, and I have no idea why.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I believe I am using the wrong substitution, any hints?

Comment: Nitpicks that don't really affect the final answer, but I think might be beneficial to be pointed out: 1) $dx \ne 1$, but rather $dx = du$, and you evaluate the final answer from $u=0$ to $u = 1$, not $x=\ldots$.  These aren't issues with the mechanics of the calculation, but rather things that gave me more insight when I understood them. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea for what to pick for $u$, but your error is because you have completely ignored the $x$ outside of the square root.  What you should have is this:

If you have $u = \color{red}{x-26}$, this means $x = \color{blue}{u+26}$.  Your limit changes are right, so this is:
$$\begin{align}\int_{26}^{27}\color{blue}{x}\sqrt{\color{red}{x-26}}\,dx &= \int_0^1\color{blue}{(u+26)}\sqrt{\color{red}{u}}\,du\\
&= \int_0^1u^{3/2}+26u^{1/2}\,du\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}$$

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Your present substitution doesn't work because the factor $x$ in front of the squareroot is mapped to $26 + u$. Just remember to include this factor, and everything should work out fine.